# What is this matrix expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a matrix $A$ and vector $b$, the following expression is acquired.

$$C_{ij} = \sum_k A_{ki} A_{kj} b_k$$

Can I reformulate this $C$ by $A, b$ without using the indices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\sum_j A_{ij}B_{jk} = (AB)_{ik}$. Hence your expression gives
$$C = A^T \operatorname{diag}(b) A$$